# Create a contour plot in MATLAB with 3 vectors and x, y vectors on a logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, vector, contour, logarithm

I've got 3 vectors

```
x =[10^(-10) 10^(-9) 10^(-8) 10^(-7) 10^(-6) 10^(-5) 10^(-4) 10^(-3) 10^(-2)]

y =[10^(-10) 10^(-9) 10^(-8) 10^(-7) 10^(-6) 10^(-5) 10^(-4) 10^(-3) 10^(-2)]
```

and z which is the error that takes values from 5 to 0.01.

I need to create a contour plot. However, I cannot use meshgrid, as the step on my x and y axis should be very small and Matlab crashes when I'm trying that.

Any ideas about resolving it?

Comment: If the x and y axes are to be in log scale they would simply show up as a linear grid (at least for the values you've shown). Why not just use x = [2:10], y = [2:10] (linear scale where the value represents the exponent) and the same z vales as you would have when using log scale x and y?

Comment: So, how do I create my meshgrid? I need to create a meshgrid in order to have a contour plot, right?

Comment: You have 9x9 = 81 z points correct?

Comment: Actually my x vector is [10^(-10) 10^(-9) 10^(-8) 10^(-7) 10^(-6) 10^(-5) 10^(-4) 10^(-3) 10^(-2) 10^(-1) 10^(-0)..(11 times)      and my y vector is [10^(-10) 10(-10) (11 times) 10(-9) 10^(-9) (11 times).... 10(0) 10(0) (11 times)], so each vector has a length of 121. The z values are the resulting error from my model simulation from every pair between parameters x and y, so I have also 121 in my z vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meshgrid to produce the required mesh and replace the labels later on. The properties you are looking for are called XTick and XTickLabel. See for example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565

Comment: How do I actually create meshgrid with the x and y vectors that I've got?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, just use the indices of the x- and y-vectors, i.e. in case of x: 1->10^-10, 2->10^-9, ... The mapping of these values may be resolved using XTickLabel once the plot is created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a logarithmic scale to see the results in any sensible way. Practically, this means you should probably do

```
x = logspace(-10, -2, 9);
y = logspace(-10, -2, 9);

logX = log(x);
logY = log(y);

[lxx lyy]=meshgrid(logX, logY);
```

and then plot contours as usual with

```
contour(lxx, lyy, reshape(z, [9 9]));
```

Finally, you would want to annotate your axes to show you are using a log scale - or you can turn off the tick labels and replace them with your own values.

Alternatively, I wonder if you could use the grid you have

```
[xx yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
```

and after plotting the contour, doing

```
set(gca, 'xscale', 'log');
set(gca, 'yscale', 'log');
```

I can't test this right now, so this may be bad advice. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really work. The problem is I've got vectors:       x =  [10^(-10) 10^(-9) 10^(-8) 10^(-7) 10^(-6) 10^(-5) 10^(-4) 10^(-3) 10^(-2) 10^(-1) 10^(-0)..(11 times) and                     y = [10^(-10) 10(-10) (11 times) 10(-9) 10^(-9) (11 times).... 10(0) 10(0) (11 times)]    z is also a vector, so contour plot does not work when z is left as a vector.

Comment: See edit. I created `x` and `y` vectors that are non-repeated, then `xx` and `yy` (or `lxx` and `lyy` for log versions) that are a regular grid. And then reshape your `z` vector into a 9x9 matrix with `reshape(x, [9 9])`, and plot with `contour(lxx, lyy, reshape(x, [9 9]));`